# Generate XML for each group in the table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the below data which I need to group with `buid`, `duid` and `aid`

```
INSERT INTO XmlTable (id, cid, aid, buid, duid) 
VALUES(624220, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(625475, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(659989, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(660076, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(660089, 68487905, 33, '7C06311E', '7C06311E')
,(660361, 68487905, 33, '7C06311E', '7C06311E')
,(662592, 68487905, 33, '3501549D', 'AD8AB9EC')
,(663011, 68487905, 33, '3501549D', 'AD8AB9EC');
```

and generate the corresponding xml list which contains respective `id`, `cid` for each of these groups.

```
<IList>
    <drive aid="33" buid="77D8B242" duid="DF6DC7D0">
        <files id="624220" cid="68487905"/>
        <files id="625475" cid="68487905"/>
        <files id="659989" cid="68487905"/>
        <files id="660076" cid="68487905"/>
    </drive>
    <drive aid="33" buid="7C06311E" duid="7C06311E">
        <files id="660089" cid="68487905"/>
        <files id="660361" cid="68487905"/>
    </drive>
    <drive aid="33" buid="3501549D" duid="AD8AB9EC">
        <files id="662592" cid="68487905"/>
        <files id="663011" cid="68487905"/>
    </drive>
</IList>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE
(
    id INT,
    cid INT,
    aid INT,
    buid VARCHAR(10),
    duid VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @XmlTable (id, cid, aid, buid, duid) 
VALUES(624220, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(625475, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(659989, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(660076, 68487905, 33, '77D8B242', 'DF6DC7D0')
,(660089, 68487905, 33, '7C06311E', '7C06311E')
,(660361, 68487905, 33, '7C06311E', '7C06311E')
,(662592, 68487905, 33, '3501549D', 'AD8AB9EC')
,(663011, 68487905, 33, '3501549D', 'AD8AB9EC');

SELECT
    aid AS '@aid',
    buid AS '@buid',
    duid AS '@duid',
    (
        SELECT
            id AS '@id',
            cid AS '@cid'
        FROM
            @XmlTable AS T2
        WHERE
            T2.aid = T1.aid
            AND T2.buid = T1.buid
            AND T2.duid = T1.duid
        FOR XML PATH('files'), TYPE
    )
FROM
    @XmlTable AS T1
GROUP BY
    aid, buid, duid
FOR XML PATH('drive'), ROOT('IList');
```

For me this has the right output:

[image]

Comment: Courtesy fiddle :-) https://dbfiddle.uk/NbgYdq52?hide=2

Comment: I really should get that in my system, thanks for the Addition Peter :)

Comment: Actually, limited support for pretty-print XML just got added. The pretty-print link for this code snippet is https://dbfiddle.uk/C-mVFASS?hide=2